# Whatsapp on dual sim

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, dual-sim

I want to use dual sim phone with one number registered with whatsapp and another number with data pack , is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use dual sim phone with one number registered with whatsapp and another number with data pack , is it possible?

Yes. In dual sim Android phones, you can only use one sim's mobile data at once. You can choose which sim to be used with mobile data in settings.

And WhatsApp doesn't require the same sim's mobile data. After installing and sms/cal verification, you can use any means of data connection to use WhatsApp. Even you can remove the sim and use the application as long as you didn't reverify Whatsapp sms/cal from a different phone.

On dual sim phones, you can even use two whatsapp accounts for both sims if your android version supports multiple user. Android Lolipop and above supports multiple users on phones. While you can enable multiple users on Android 4.2 to 4.4, you may need root access and `build.prop` tweak to do that. Just create a second user and install WhatsApp in it and register it with second sim.

Using modified version of whatsapp on the same user account with official app might have issues, since both apps share the common directory "WhatsApp" on sdcard, conflicting with database.

Comment: Thankyou Bharat for your crisp & precise answer. Excellent explanation that answered my main concern.

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

**No**, because WhatsApp doesn't officially support multiple accounts.

### Longer Answer

It's technically possible, but you'll need two different versions of WhatsApp. Customised ('*modded'*) versions of WhatsApp exist, and if you install both the official version and a reliable unofficial version, you can in fact have two WhatsApp numbers on the same phone.

However, you shouldn't do this if you're concerned about privacy because the unofficial versions of WhatsApp aren't vetted by any authority and might compromise your device.

Furthermore, there always remains a possibility the unofficial version will simply stop working, because WhatsApp doesn't like them and has begun [cracking down on them](http://techcrunch.com/2015/03/06/whatsapp-says-its-not-permanently-banning-users-from-its-service-just-blocking-third-party-clients/). There are even (unsubstantiated, and later refuted) rumours that WhatsApp will permanently ban users of unofficial clients.

Instead of installing an unofficial version, you *can* edit the `build.prop` file to make it appear as if two copies of WhatsApp are completely different applications but you will definitely run into issues later on as both will try to save messages and media to the `/sdcard/WhatsApp` folder, resulting in conflicts and confusion.

Comment: Which unofficial version do you recommend? I tried to use OGWhatsApp, did not work for me. Time zone is not correct was the error. Useless...